# How to find dynamically a key values inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key

each API request I'm making contains different keys values inside a specific object.
How can I dynamically get the Number value of the second key? ("123112042")

```
"salesRanks": {
    "281052": [ keepaTime, salesRank, ... ]
    "123112042": [ keepaTime, salesRank, ... ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and get the second index.

```js
const data = {
  salesRanks: {
    "281052": [1, 1],
    "123112042": [2, 2]
  }
};

console.log(Object.keys(data.salesRanks)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although an object's keys are not really meant to be ordered, you could write an object iterator and assign with destructuring like this:

```js
const obj = {
  salesRanks: {
    281052: ["keepaTime", "salesRank"],
    123112042: ["keepaTime", "salesRank"],
    [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
      return Object.keys(this).values();
    }
  },
};

const {
  salesRanks: [, second],
} = obj;

console.log(second);
```